# Akka-http-testkit returns nested list instead of flattened one

Tags: scala, scalatest, akka-http, akka-testkit

I'm using `akka-http-testkit` for testing routes and `scalamock` for mocking my class. The endpoint is a `GET` with a payload.

I'v got a method which return `Future[List[Map[String, Any]]]` - basically raw rows from the DB. It works ok with curl, but my assertion fails on comparing JSON because it has `[[` and `]]` instead of `[` and `]`.

I'm not sure why, because with curl it works fine - that's my test code:

```
"return correct json from mock" in {

  val getRequest = HttpRequest(
    HttpMethods.GET,
    uri = "/endpoint",
    entity = HttpEntity(MediaTypes.`application/json`, jsonStringRequest))
    val fake = stub[FakeService]
    (fake.query (_: String, _: MyParsedObject)(_: ExecutionContext)) when ("endpoint", myParsedObject, ec) returns Future.successful(responseAsMap)

    getRequest ~> route ~> check {
      responseAs[String] shouldBe jsonStringResponse
    }
}
```

And thats my error:

```
"[[ { "aaa" : 123}, { "aaa" : 123 } ]]" 
was not equal to "[ { "aaa" : 123}, { "aaa" : 123 } ]"
```

Does it have something to do with it being `Future[T]` instead of `T`? 
How can I fix it?

Comment: Could you show as your `responseAsMap` and  `jsonStringResponse` definitions as well?

Comment: I'm pretty much sure that while creating your mock data i.e `jsonStringResponse ` , data logic is called twice. As @SergGr said , please share you `jsonStringResponse ` how are you creating it.

Comment: I'm dumb, sorry it was my mistake, I forgot to put my json objects into list